# Can I ask a question here related to proving a physical property about the rendering equation?

Tags: support, allowed-questions

On Meta Stack Exchange, I posted [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/347689/380248) about where I should post a question I have. I was asked to ask here whether this forum is the appropriate place.

---

In computer graphics, many ray tracers approximate the [Rendering Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rendering_equation) up to a specific depth. Intuitively, this is okay because the deeper a path is, the more energy it will absorb. As I cannot find any online resource that proves this mathematically, I have tried to do so myself using the rendering equation, but without luck. I would like some help in proving it, and I think others can benefit from having a reference to such a proof.

**Problem**

- The question is too computer-sciency for the Physics forum. (I cannot find any tags that would be related to my question. Although the rendering equation is based on physics, it is actually nowhere to be found in the branch of physics itself.)
- The question is too mathematical for the Computer Graphics forum. (These questions are more about graphics, not so much about their mathematical foundations. There doesn't even exist a tag named rendering-equation :(.)
- I fear that the question might be too physical for the Mathematics forum. (The rendering equation and the property I would like to proof have a physical foundation. Also "It's just integrals? Ask a physicist!")

Is this the right network to post my question?

---

As a side note, I actually posted [my question on the Graphics forum](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/q/9809/13225), but without reaction for the reason I mentioned, and because this forum is still in beta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an equation, you want to prove a property about it, and you even have context to bring along with it. This is a good question for Mathematics.